# Derivative of complicated integral, help needed

Tags: calculus

I've been working on some homework problems for my calculus course and I got stumped when trying to find the derivative of this integral.

$$
H(x) = \int_3^{\int_1^x\sin^3t dt}\frac{dt}{1+t^2+\sin^6t}
$$

My problem involves the upper bound being another integral, the steps I used before in solving other similar problems doesn't seem to work here (FTOC and chain rule properties), any tips or help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How about you show us what you've tried given how it worked on previous problems?

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:** Use the formula
$$
\frac{d}{dx}\int_{f(x)}^{g(x)}h(t,x)\,dt
=h(g(x),x)g'(x)-h(f(x),x)f'(x)+\int_{f(x)}^{g(x)}\frac{d}{dx}h(t,x)\,dt
$$

Comment: I would guess the OP is looking for the $x$-derivative in which case the last term in your expression isn't needed since $h(t,x)$ is $x$-independent.

Comment: For the same reason even the second summand vanishes; this formula is the most general one. Form this he can get the requested result

Answer (score 0):

Take it step by step. Fundamental theorem of calculus and chain rule are all you need here:

**Hint:**

- Let $G(x)= \int_3^{x}\frac{dt}{1+t^2+\sin^6t}$, what is the derivative of $G$?
- Let $b(x)=\int_1^x\sin^3t dt$, what is the derivative of $b$?
- How do you express $H$ in terms of $G$ and $b$?
- Conclude

---

**Sidenote:**

Depending on what you studied and what you know, you may actually find a closed form for $b$ fairly easily (although I'm sure this already has an answer on this site). Finding that form enables you to get rid of all integrals.